# Why does my azure function sometimes fail to read a static configuration variable?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function that needs to make an http call, and it retrieves the uri from a configuration variable that I've ensured exists in the function configuration section, in the Azure portal.

When I run my function in Azure, I've noticed that roughly 80% of the time, my function fails to read the value from the function configuration, i.e. the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("endpoint_value_from_configuration") method call returns null.

However if I repeatedly test this function (without changing any code or configuration whatsoever) it does sometimes succeed to read the variable.  What's going on here?  How can I change this function so that this problem does not occur?

```
[FunctionName("MessageHandler")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%Topic%", "subname", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string mySbMsg,
    ILogger log)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BusinessObject>(mySbMsg);
    var endpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("endpoint_value_from_configuration");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the response here by *Pitchmatt* - [Reading settings from a Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556311/reading-settings-from-a-azure-function)

If you are using **V2**, you need to use below code:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

And then, use config to fetch settings:

```
var endpoint = config["endpoint_value_from_configuration"]
```

When debugging locally, it gets the settings from `local.settings.json` under the "Values" keyword. When running in Azure, it gets the settings from the Application settings tab.